# Can we have a 'back to top' button or link on the bottom of the homepage?

Tags: feature-request, homepage

When scrolling the questions that are 'interesting' or other tabs on the home page.

If you reach the bottom there is only a 'want more? see complete listing' link. 
The suggestion is to put an extra link, or a minimal 'back to top' icon on the bottom of the page for usability?

I really like scrolling these questions and this would improve the user experience for everybody.

Comment: Can't you use the "Home" key?

Comment: yes, but that is almost the same as pressing F5 or a bookmark (for me, I know there is no refresh with 'home'). I mainly scroll using the mouse, and this is more of a usability request.

Comment: If you're already using your mouse to scroll, it's hardly any effort to drag the scroll bar to the top, or click in the scroll bar...

Comment: Again, not about alternatives, about usability.

Comment: How is a back to top link more usable than your home key?

Comment: What you people mean by home key?

Comment: it is not, and that also is not what the question is about, it is about usability when using a mouse scrolling stackoverflow, [usability] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability) is not about what performs the execution best, but about ease of access. You may consider me a lazy person for always wanting to search the home key on the many laptops I have to use.

Comment: Any good programmer is inherently (necessarily) lazy so I don't think we need to talk about that ;) Could you detail exactly how adding another method of scrolling to the top of the page improves both **"ease of use"** and **"learnability"**, per your Wikipedia-backed definition of the word? I'm especially interested in how you think this would improve "learnability" of the site. To me it seems counter-intuitive that augmenting the existing methods of scrolling to the top with a new one could be more "learnable". Have you any data/studies/other info to share that could help back up your case?

Comment: @AvinashRaj http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_key

Comment: ease of use: having a convenient way of going back to top without needing to know that 'home' does this. Even not all devellopers know to browse webpages with keyboardshortcuts if it's not in their area of expertise

Comment: I hardly think you can call using a keyboard or web browser to be an "area of expertise". People browse the web whether they are web developers or not, it doesn't change the buttons on their keyboard or their knowledge of using them. I didn't spot your response to the question about how the new feature would improve "learnability". Any comments there or was that simply a part of the definition you hadn't considered before posting this question?

Comment: as per learnability: the easier it is to use, the easier it is to learn. learning to use a site is harder to descript than using a program since there are more pre-existing expectations, but this aspect of usability on this particular example is that if you want a method to go back to top after scrolling the 100 questions, you somehow have to know what the home key does following your eplanation. Or could there be a button that does exactly that?

Comment: as I was typing the previous comment you commented back. If you read the comment again you can see that the area of expertise is not using a keyboard for browsing the web, but just their field. I for example know it does that because in my education (in my last year) someone told me that also was an option. I think the person not knowing what the home key is somewhat proves my point

Comment: I don't agree with that. If "learnability" is to be implied by "ease of use", it wouldn't be mentioned separately in the definition of the word "usability". But I don't have the time to address your points fully. Suffice to say I think you're trying to fix a problem that only you, or at least a very small percentage of the population, have with using the already-existing methods to get to the top of the page. You could always buy a mouse with programmable buttons if it bothers you enough, don't forget.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your opininion. Suffice to say, that you apparantly think that most people use their keyboards for the web, I did not and that is why I asked this question. but it cannot really be quantified unless stackoverflow would have a questionnaire.

Comment: Mac users doesn't have the home key...

Comment: @user1007522, `fn` + `PageUp`, or something like this. I'm not on a native keyboard.

Comment: @Clive I'm with ThMBc on this, a link at the bottom would be nice to have. I rarely use my keyboard to browse the web, I find it annoying to have to do that, it make me waste time to think about finding the proper key or key combo to do what I want while a link would be enough.

Comment: @ChrisF No, I don't want to use my "Home" key as a link would be both faster and easier than having to waste time making my left hand move to the home key. On questions with a lot of answers, scrolling back up once done is annoying.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau What good is a link at the bottom of the page, though if your issue is with upwards scrolling? Are you saying it's less annoying to scroll back up if you're halfway down a page, three-quarters down, 7/9ths of the way down? What's the cut-off point that makes this feature necessary?

Comment: @Clive When at the bottom... obviously, not being at the bottom, the link can be pointless but it isn't uncommon to get to the bottom of a question, at least for me.

Comment: @Clive Why would a link at the bottom bother anyone that wouldn't use it in the first place? I just don't get why there's people arguing it would be useless.

Comment: It doesn't bother me @Jonathan - but I'm not advocating for a change, you are. A picture of a cat at the bottom of the page wouldn't 'bother' me either, but I would question whether we actually need developers to spend time implementing it

Comment: @Clive We need a unicorn picture for sure...

Comment: Too true @JonathanDrapeau ;)

Comment: This isn't Stack Overflow's job. It's your browser's job.

Learn to use the tools your browser gives you, and you have a consistent set of tools you can use everywhere, on every site. It's not up to individual sites to solve these problems.

Comment: My laptop doesn't have a "home" key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I improved the experience for myself with the following [userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userscript).
Add more CSS and jQuery features as desired.

<sup><sub>(tested on Opera, FF and Chrome)</sub></sup>

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         (SE) Back to top
// @namespace    stackapps.com/users/10590/brasofilo
// @version      1.0
// @description  Add back to top feature to Stack sites
// @homepage     http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274949
// @author       brasofilo
// @license MIT  http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @exclude       *://chat.*
// @exclude       *://blog.*
// @exclude       *://api.*
// @exclude       *://data.*
// @grant         addGlobalStyle
// ==/UserScript==

help_se_add_jquery( start_up );

function help_se_add_jquery( callback ){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function start_up($) {
    $('body').append('<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>');
    var offset = 420;
    var duration = 150;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
        } else {
            $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
        }
    });
    $('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
        return false;
    });
}

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css
    head.appendChild(style);
}

// Attention to preserve the open and close comment
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558082
addGlobalStyle (function(){/*
    .back-to-top {
        position: fixed; bottom: 2em; right: -3px; text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000; background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.80); font-size: 12px;
        padding: .5em; display: none; border-radius: 5px
    }
    .back-to-top:hover { background-color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.50); }
 */
}.toString().slice(14,-3));
```

**Result:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I hadn't thought about making a userscript. great idea! maybe some day a real feature..! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Learn to use the <kbd>Home</kbd> (for Windows) key as others have suggested. I actually did not know that worked. But it does and now I would feel silly asking for yet another widget to clutter up my page.

per @Matt 's comment:
OSX - use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: In OSX: ⌘+↑ (tested in Safari and Firefox)